# Team Foundation server: help for starters

Tags: sql-server, version-control, tfs

I have installed TFS on my local dev machine and I want to "version control" my small project using TFS. However I have having trouble configuring TFS on my machine to get started. Can you please point me to some basic , starter internet resources for installing, configuring TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a small project, and for running on your machine, Git or Subversion seem to be much better choices.

Comment: But I want to use Team Foundation server

Comment: While it may be true, it is pretty useless as far as answering the question goes.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN documentation is your best starting point.  The [Getting Started Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286491.aspx) is probably a good first topic.